# ELF error when trying to deploy solana anchor program

Tags: anchor, solana-program

I'm new to solana. When i run solana program deploy target/release/libsol_contract.so it shows ELF error: Failed to parse

Lib.rs:

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

declare_id!("11111111111111111111111111111111");

#[program]
mod hello_world {
    use super::*;
    pub fn say_hello(_ctx: Context<SayHello>) -> Result<()> {
        msg!("Hello World!");       
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct SayHello {}
```

When I run `solana program deploy target/release/libsol_contract.so` I get:

```
Error: ELF error: ELF error: Failed to parse ELF file: Section or symbol name .note.gnu.build- is longer than 16 bytes
```

Comment: Please provide full error and your code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Akhtar can you check now, I have included the contract and the error.

Comment: Maybe id can’t be 11111111111111111111111111111111

Comment: @wei1769 what should be used in the place of id?

Comment: Use the keypair’s public key in the ./target/deploy folder.

Comment: I see, you’re using the wrong build command. See my answer below

Answer (score 1):

When using the anchor framework you should use the **anchor deploy** command.
If it's the first time building the project you should run the **anchor build** command. This will compile your project and install all the necessary dependencies.

Note: It's important to consider how you've installed Anchor. I recommend installing using the **Anchor Version Manager**(AVM), this will significantly reduce the likelihood of encountering dependency-related issues.

Answer (score 0):

The program’s build command is not `cargo build —-release` it should be `cargo build-sbf`.

Comment: I have deployed the contract, how to call the function from the cli ?

Comment: You need to write a test file.